# Error Code 1005 in mysql while applying Foreign key to a table

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am having two tables `tbluserlogindetail` and `tblRoles`.

`tbluserlogindetail` is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `tbluserlogindetail` (
`LoginID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`LoginID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `LoginID_UNIQUE` (`LoginID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

EDIT `doratesting`.`tbluserlogindetail`;

and my second table `tblRoles` is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `tblroles` (
  `RoleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LoginID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RoleID`,`LoginID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

I tried the the following to assign a primary key for the column `LoginID` in `tblroles` table but i don't know where i went wrong can any one help me.

I have gone through the documentation but unable to rectify the error so please help me

`ALTER TABLE tblroles
ADD FOREIGN KEY (loginid)
REFERENCES tbluserlogindetail(loginid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced columns must be unique in the referenced table. Try one of these options:

- The primary key on `tbluserlogindetail` is `(ID, loginid)` so you could use that as your foreign key instead of `(loginid)`. This will require you to add a column `tbluserlogindetail_ID` to `tblroles`.
- Try adding a unique index to the `LoginID` column of the `tbluserlogindetail` table. This is only possible if it is actually unique.

Also, why is your primary key on `tbluserlogindetail` defined as `PRIMARY KEY (ID, LoginID)`? The `ID` field is an auto-increment field and is already unique. So why do you also include the LoginID as part of the primary key? I think you need to go back to your table design and rethink which columns to choose as your primary keys.

Comment: didn't get you can you tell where should i make changes

Comment: Hi `Mark Byers` i am having a question if i add as per you said can i insert multiple values means i will have `LoginID` and `RoleID` which can be inserted for multiple times

Comment: Hi `Mark Byers` as `LoginID` should be unique in my table so i make it as a primary key

Comment: @User: The primary key of your table is **not** `LoginID`. You have defined the key as `(ID, LoginID)` which is something *entirely different* (and probably wrong). The way you have defined your table  would allow for duplicates in the `LoginId` column. Don't believe it? Try it: `INSERT INTO tbluserlogindetail (LoginID) VALUES ('a'),('a');` Result `2 row(s) affected`. You almost certainly need to change the primary key on both tables.

Comment: `Mark Byers` ok i added `Unique` key for `LoginID`

Comment: @User: You don't need a primary key *and* unique key... a primary key is already unique by definition.

Comment: Ok i got it by just adding a single primary key to the `tbluserlogindetail` thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

this is just guess/ assumption ,i like to share here,

`PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`LoginID`)`

in tbluserlogindetail are considered as surrogate key,

when we  execute the child table,That is tblroles,

child table expected primary key in parent table,

but actually we created the surrogate key, due to this reason, i alter query failed,

```
ALTER TABLE tblroles ADD FOREIGN KEY (LoginID) REFERENCES tbluserlogindetail(LoginID)
```

This is my assumption, give feedback for my answer,

I did following changes to execute the Alter table command:
1.`tblroles` create with given Create query command, after created i manually deleted the 
`LoginID` primary key in tblroles table,

1. Changed varchar to int in LoginID,
2. in `tbluserlogindetail`, deleted the  `ID` AUTO_INCREMENT,Pk.
3. Check i updated ALTER query